# How to create singleton with vars in its constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I have this singleton in my angular project:

```
class CustomersServicesHandler
{
    private static _instance: CustomersServicesHandler;

    bridalEventId: string = null;

    private constructor(private _customerService: CustomersService,
        private _globalFunctionsService: GlobalFunctionsService)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static get Instance()
    {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());//this is my problem
    }
}
```

As you cam see, I'm using some services in my constructor.
The Problem starts when I create `new this()` - I need to pass the variables (services) which also getting variables.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Angular services are by default singletons, if not provided else, e.g. in a component

Comment: As @Batajus said angular can handle this for you with DI and services, you should read this: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject the `CustomersServicesHandler` in the class you want to use it in:

```
class ClassYouWantToUseItIn {
    constructor(private customersServicesHandler: CustomersServicesHandler) {
    }
}
```

Angular will handle the creation/passing of `CustomersService` and `GlobalFunctionsService` for you.